# Hide/show element after append

Tags: php, jquery

```js
$("ol").append("<div id='save' style='display:none'>Save<div>");
$("li").mouseup(function() {
   $('#save').show();
});
$("ol").sortable();
$("body").on('click','#save',function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

snippet above working correctly with js append.
How to show an element after append by php using mouseup?

So, I have draggable list. And, I need to show element every time the user changes the list order. Every time the element is dropped, I call a function as shown:

```
$("li").mouseup(function() {
   $('#save').show();
});
$("ol").sortable();
```

When the user clicks save button, I hide it using:

```
$("body").on('click','#save',function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
```

But how do I make it visible again? `$('#save').show();` isn't working!

funniest thing:
my php generate 2 buttons, like that:

```
<div class="buttons"><button id="saveTit" style="display: none" >Save content</button></div>

<div class="buttons"><button class="butClick" data-con='<?php echo $content?>'>Add new row</button></div>
```

To call 2nd button i use:

```
$(".butClick").on('click',function(){
      alert($(this).attr('data-tit'));
})
```

but to call 1st one i have to use body selector... any idea why?!

I change id for class inside div and to call a event...
And it works...

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) for this? It will make it easier for others to understand your problem.

Comment: Don't use jsfiddle - there's no reason.  If you can create a **[mcve]** to demonstrate the issue then do it in a snippet on this page (use the `<>` button in the editor).

Comment: Plus one for @Archer's comment. I guess I'm still stuck in the past!

Comment: ye just creating snippet

Comment: I can't did it o snippet.... because i use php to generate data...  when i use js append every think work... so adding snippet on that example have no sense i will have to give brief explain

Comment: Now can somebody explain me why that code works??!! I change id for class  and everything works?? any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to change the div to hidden instead and use the prop function instead of show and hide :

```js
$("ol").append("<div id='save' hidden>Save<div>");
$("li").mouseup(function() {
   $('#save').prop("hidden",false);
});
$("ol").sortable();
$("body").on('click','#save',function(){
    $(this).prop("hidden",true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<ol id='some123'>Items
  <li draggable='true'>Item 1</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 2</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 3</li>
  <li draggable='true'>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: as i said i need to use php to generate data... i knot that works on js xD   but anyway.. i work it out